# Enable Tracing for a plugin in Eclipse install

Tags: eclipse, trace, pde

I'd like to enable tracing for org.eclipse.wst.server.core plug-in for an eclipse install. I've read that I'd require a .options file in the eclipse installation folder. 
The content of the .options file:

```
org.eclipse.wst.server.core/debug=true
org.eclipse.wst.server.core/extension_point=true
```

I also have -debug option specified in eclipse.ini. Here is sts/eclipse.ini contents:

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-debug
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/sts.icns
```

The file is located under eclipse folder (same place where eclipse.ini is located)
This doesn't work. I don't see the trace statements in the log.
Anyone knows what is wrong with this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to start Eclipse with the `-debug` option to turn this on.

You can also specify `-debug filename` to specify a different path for the options file

Comment: Is eclipse.ini the right place to put the -debug option?

Comment: eclipse.ini or the command line. In eclipse.ini it must be before any -vmargs

Comment: I've added -debug but it didn't help. I've listed the contents of my INI file just in case. Is there anything else i might be missing?

Comment: Perhaps I'm not looking in the right place for the log file? I'm opening <my workspace folder>/.metadata/.log file and think it's a log file. Is this correct?

Comment: Worked when i specified the path to the .options file correctly. That is sufficient for me to progress. Thanks for taking the time and answering my question :-)